# html5boilerplate/ Google Analytics - Tracking code is not installed

Tags: google-analytics, html5boilerplate

I am using html5boilerplate template and I have a problem with google analytics. I changed the UA-XXXXX-X to my tracking number as it is written two days ago and still got message on analtics page "Tracking not installed"? Is there anything else I need to do what I forgot? I also have a console error Failed to load resource http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js. Is this the problem here? How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your site?

Comment: if your site is https (and even if it's not) - you should be using the code [exactly as it appears in the template](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L37). Whatever the cause, the js error is the reason it's not working (surprise =)).

Comment: @AD7six I have not changed anything in this code except UA-XXXXX-X,  anyway.. everything is ok now and works, don't know why it took so long but nvm anymore.

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours for the Google Analytics servers to update -- [Source: Google Documentation - Check your web tracking code setup](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en)